# Ubuntu/Debian no sound - fast and uncontrolled switching output device between headphones and speakers

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, speakers

I've gotten dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 10 since two years. 3/4 months ago I lost sound on Ubuntu 18.04 (it is working properly on Windows). I want to fix this so much!
I use Asus Zenbook UX433 with Realtek.

The output device in settings is instantly switching between headphones and speakers, sound is intermittent.

I reinstalled and updated ubuntu - didn't heleped. I installed debian - still doesn't work. I've made a lot of internet advices, but nothing helped. Before installing debian there was such mess, that none of devices (input or output) wasn't displayed in options, sometimes there was HDMI output (when nothing was plugged in).

Does anyone has some advice?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to use?

Comment: Error had shown on Ubuntu 18.04, than I updated to 20.04. Yesterday I installed Debian 10.

Comment: ok Debian is not supported on this site Feel free to re install Ubuntu and maybe someone on this site can help you.